# linking to a tab on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are currently using a jQuery to setup our table with tabs. We want to direct users from a different page to tab4 of this page. The problem we are having is that it refuses to link to tab4 it will only link back to the first tab. We are using

```
 $(".tabContent").hide();
 $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
 $(".tabContent:first").show();

 $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
   $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   $(".tabContent").hide();
   var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
   $(activeTab).fadeIn();
   return false;
});
```

I am quite new at this so any in depth explanation would be greatly appreciated. If anymore information is needed just let me know.

Comment: Are you sure about `var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");`? All it does is assign `activeTab` with the string value of the hyperling destination. I don't think that's a valid selector for `$(activeTab).fadeIn()`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `id` of the fourth tab to something like `tab4`. Then, simply link to it like: `http://example.com/page.html#tab4`.

If that doesn't work, you could use `PHP`, if possible:

```
<?php
$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;
switch ($page) {
    case 1:
        // code to switch to tab 1
        break;
    case 2:
        // code to switch to tab 2
        break;
    case 3:
        // code to switch to tab 3
        break;
    case 4:
        // code to switch to tab 4
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: I did set the id for the tab as tab4 and it will take you to the page but it will not open tab4. It opens onto tab1 and then you have to click on tab4 in order for it to open.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash symbol "#" in your url and watch it with window.onhashchange event (its not crossbrowser).

Or you can use crossbrowser jquery [hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) - [example use](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/).

Comment: So I tired the crossover and it did allow my hash's to show up when i click on the different tabs but when you try and go to the website and #tab4 for example it will load the page but have tab1 open instead of tab4. The website url still registers the #tab4 though and if you go to any other tab it will change.